# What is the Default ActionBar Title Font Size?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Seems to be 17dip. Just want to confirm it if anyone knows the exact size.

Comment: For anyone looking to know this for the material design toolbar, I found this: `<dimen name="abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar">20dp</dimen>`

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The short one…

`$ grep ActionBar platforms/android-11/data/res/values/*` leads to

styles.xml:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
</style>

[…]

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! So what are Medium and Small referring to? Also, it seems like I can only change the text size on API 13+, so wouldn't this cause inconsistency for tablets running 3.0 vs 3.2?

Comment: styles.xml and themes.xml contain the default Theme and Theme.Holo definitions. TextAppearance.Medium is a named style (with inheritance, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance) defined using the style element. You can define your own Foo.Bar style if wanted… Not knowing how do you try to change the text size, I suggest you to define your own style/theme if you would some application-wide look and feel consistency. Post a new question describing what's your needs and put the link there ;)

Answer (score 88):

This works for me.

This is what I do to get the default toolbar style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This does the trick to keep the default style `style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"`

Then in your activity, you can do:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
mTitle.setText("Custom...");
```

Comment: Or @style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title

Comment: No. This style is exists.

Comment: Note that attribute name is just `style`, not `android:textStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get the text size of title and subtitle of `Toolbar`

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.myToolbar)
val titleSize =
    (toolbar.getChildAt(0) as AppCompatTextView).textSize / resources.displayMetrics.density
val subTitleSize =
    (toolbar.getChildAt(1) as AppCompatTextView).textSize / resources.displayMetrics.density
// hard code position 0 for title and 1 for subTitle may not work in all case, depend in your case, you can use a suitable value

Log.i("TAG", "title size $titleSize")
Log.i("TAG", "sub title size $subTitleSize")
```

with my current theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` with `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`. title size is 20 and subtitle is 16