# How to change text size of title action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title, searchview

I have been trying to implement a SearchView on action bar in my project. I want to change text size of title action bar. Is it to possible?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897071/how-to-change-size-of-titles-text-on-action-bar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133290/what-is-the-default-actionbar-title-font-size

Comment: I alread ygo through this link but did not getting any help from that link. @JaiSoni

Answer (score 0):

Create a custome style in style.xml and add into application in manifst.xml file like:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/TestStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TestStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
<item name="android:divider">#ff6600</item>
<item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Custom Action bar for that:
for this you can find action bar and use this code to set custom Action Bar like:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
    ab.setCustomView(actionBarView);
```

enjoy your code :)-

Comment: What will the UI of action bar @PiyushGupta

Comment: How to set background color, text size, text color, alignment and all?? @PiyushGupta

Comment: ohk dear.there is an xml file over my code *custom_action_bar* now in this class you can modify all things with your Ui of ActionBar.