# How to change my action bar text color and font size in android

Tags: android

i am new to android how to change my app name text color and font size ,my default text color was black i want change it to White color and increase my font size  please any one help me

**style.xml**

my default text color was black i want change it to White color

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">        
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/tabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#029C7A</item>        
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">       
    <item name="android:textColor">#CFCFC4</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style> 

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="tabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>    
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. What have you tried so far?

Comment: <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        </style>    i tried this one but no use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133290/what-is-the-default-actionbar-title-font-size

Comment: I want to change my title text color

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to add this

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>ActionBarTitle </font>"));
```

for font size

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>

</style>
```

Comment: add small tag for that or else you can change it in your styles

Answer (score 4):

Using AppCompat Theme, it can be done in this way. Define a custom style in styles.xml as follows:

```
<style name="CustomToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">add_colour_your_choice</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">add_colour_your_choice</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    </style>
```

Then in the layout of the activity where you wish to change the action bar colour add a toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="0.5dp"
        android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"/>
```

And lastly in the java file of the activity, add the following lines to onCreate after `setContentLayout`:

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Note: For this to work, you will have to add:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

to your build.gradle(module:app) under dependencies.
(There are two dependencies, one under buildscipt and one at the end. ADD the line to the one AT THE END

Answer (score 2):

I have created my own custom view and added it to action bar :

Please take a look on below code :

**How to set custom view to ActionBar ?**

```
public static ActionBar setCustomActionBar(Activity activity, ActionBar actionBar, String title) {
        if (actionBar != null) {
            ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_grey)));

            TextView actionBarTitle = (TextView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_actionbar_title);
            Typeface airplaneTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/Exo-Regular.otf");
            actionBarTitle.setText(title);
            actionBarTitle.setTypeface(airplaneTypeface);

//        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
//        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(activity, "fonts/airplane.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
//                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//        actionBar.setTitle(s);
        }
        return actionBar;
    }
```

**custom_actionbar.xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_grey"
    android:padding="@dimen/actionbar_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_up_indicator"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/actionbar_icon_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_icon_height"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_up_indicator"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_up_indicator"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/actionbar_title_left_padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/actionbar_title_left_padding"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/logo_blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title_text_size" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**How to use method :**

```
setCustomActionBar(this, getActionBar(), getResources().getString(R.string.title_actionbar_home));
```

This is a sample that shows how to create custom view and set it to actionbar.

You can modify it as per your requirement.

**Note** : Here I used my resources that I did not provided you can modify as you wish.

Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this at the below link. It worked great for me.

[Changing text size and style in action bar](https://mobikul.com/changing-text-size-style-action-bar/)

```
        ActionBar bar;
        bar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(bar!=null){
            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // Width of TextView
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Height of TextView
            tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            tv.setText(bar.getTitle());
            tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);
            bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            bar.setCustomView(tv);
        }
```