# Default android.support.v7.app.ActionBar Default Title TextSize

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-support-design

I am using AppCompatActivity and I am using the supportActionBar.

I am wondering if I could get the default value of the support ActionBar's Text Size?

Any ideas?

I would like to set it in my other TextView. Is it possible?

P.S.: My ActionBar is `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be 17dip.
For more Detail,
Refer this link It will help you.

[What is the Default ActionBar Title Font Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133290/what-is-the-default-actionbar-title-font-size)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in android sdk source code.

```
/sdk/platforms/android-23/data/res/values/styles.xml
```

Check it style name with `Widget.ActionBar`.

```
<style name="Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>
    <item name="divider">@drawable/action_bar_divider</item>
    <item name="height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="paddingStart">0dip</item>
    <item name="paddingTop">0dip</item>
    <item name="paddingEnd">0dip</item>
    <item name="paddingBottom">0dip</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small</item>
    <item name="homeLayout">@layout/action_bar_home</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Medium">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

The default value of the ActionBar's Text Size uses `TextAppearance.Medium`. So, You can set your text size in another textview by extending that style.

**Edit**

If you want to get the text style exactly like actionbar title (using toolbar to set actionbar), you can directly extend from `TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    style="@style/myTextStyle"/>
```

In your styles.xml,

```
<style name="myTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    // style your textview
</style>
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: I tried using TextAppearance.Medium, but the text Size is smaller than the standard ActionBar text size, could it be because that I am using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` ??

Comment: Hey thanks, but I dont think it comes from the `Widget.ActionBar`

Comment: Yep, you're right. If you use toolbar to set actionbar, it comes from `Widget.Toolbar`.