# What is default text size in Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have text inside a `Toolbar`, can I change `android:textSize="25sp"` to the default value for `Toolbar` itself?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Default ActionBar Title Font Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133290/what-is-the-default-actionbar-title-font-size)

Answer (score 1):

Default text size is 16sp. You can put the value as per your requirements.

Comment: Can I know variable name?

Comment: I compared between original and my own, There is different so I think it's not 16sp

Comment: @AKJA Search for `attributes.mTextSize = 15;` in the source code of [TextView](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java). It's actually roughly `15dp` or `15dpi`.